# extract specific parts from hdfs directory using awk function

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to extract specific parts from `/rec/flux_entrant/archive/le501/tble91_formation_eligible/*` directory . This directory is located in `HDFS` so that we can expose its contains using the command :
`hdfs dfs -ls /rec/flux_entrant/archive/le501/tble91_formation_eligible/*`
which return

```
/rec/flux_entrant/archive/le501/tble91_formation_eligible/20220104-221755/00000.deflate
/rec/flux_entrant/archive/le501/tble91_formation_eligible/20220103-231754/00001.deflate
/rec/flux_entrant/archive/le501/tble91_formation_eligible/20220111-152145/00002.deflate
/rec/flux_entrant/archive/le501/tble91_formation_eligible/20220112-155012/00003.deflate
```

My objectif is to extract only last part of these paths given by ( **not** **xxx.deflate** **files**) :
`20220104-221755`, `20220103-231754`, `20220111-152145` and `20220112-155012`
and then filter by those having date => `20220110`, so that, the final result should be :
`20220111-152145` and `20220112-155012` because `20220111` and `20220112` are => to **20220110**

I tried using the `awk` command using the command :

```
hdfs dfs -ls /rec/flux_entrant/archive/le501/tble91_formation_eligible/* | awk -F'/' '{split($NF, a, "-"); if (a[1]>20220110) print $NF}'
```

But this return :`00003.deflate` and `00002.deflate` **and not** `20220111-152145` and `20220112-155012`

**EDIT**

As proposed by @Tom, I used `print $(NF-1)` instead of `$NF`, but the filter was not good. I also tried to get results in list variable :

```
OUTPUT=$(hdfs dfs -ls /rec/flux_entrant/archive/le501/tble91_formation_eligible/* |
awk -F'/' '{split($NF, a, "-"); if (a[1]>=20220110) print $(NF-1)}')
echo ${OUTPUT}
```

gives

```
Found 5 items 20200916-170926 20200916-170926 20200916-170926 20200916-170926 20200916-170926 Found 5 items 20200916-182251
```

The is not good because `20200916`, `20200916` ... are not => **20220110**
Also I need to delete `Found 5 items` from the final result

Any help, please ? thank you

Comment: you should use $(NF-1)

Comment: @Tom, thank you yes, it works, but the filter no, I get a list : `Found 5 items 20200916-170926 20200916-170926 20200916-170926 20200916-170926 20200916-170926 Found 5 items 20200916-182251` as you can see no need to `Found 5 items` world also the filter seems not good

Comment: @Tom, please look to the edited question

Comment: You have to change all NF to (NF-1). You don't want the last field but the penultimate one.

Comment: @karakfa, no it returns `Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items  Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items Found 5 items`

Comment: There is nothing in your code that'll return this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, according the the [hadoop documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls), the output of `hdfs dfs -ls` looks different.

Comment: Also, you have a lexicographically sortable date-format in your directory structure so you should exploit this by just checking if `$(NF-1) > "YYYYMMDD-000000"`

Comment: Please take a look of the output for `hdfs dfs -ls /rec/flux_entrant/archive/le501/tble91_formation_eligible/* | awk -F'/' '{if ($(NF-1) > 20220110) print $(NF-1)}'`. Assigning a variable to the output is the next step. As  your system seems to behave against our expectations, let's proceed ony by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using the variable `FPAT` of AWK:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /rec/flux_entrant/archive/le501/tble91_formation_eligible/* | 
 awk -v startdate="20220110" 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{6}"}($1 >= startdate){print $1}'
```

I used the variable `startdate` to avoid hardcoding the string `20220110` into the AWK code.

Explanation: `FPAT` is a regex that describes what AWK has to consider as a field: in our case, a sequence of 8 digits, followed by an hyphen and 6 digits. AWK prints the only sequence it finds in each line of its input with the instruction `print $1`, on the condition that `($1 >= startdate)`.

Comment: thank you but return nothing

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for FPAT

Comment: When I copy the 4 lines of output of your `hdfs` command, and I filter these through my AWK command, it returns the two lines you asked for. As Ed Morton suggests, check that you have GNU AWK, just in case, issuing the command `awk --version` and posting the result here.

Comment: @PierreFrançois, I have `GNU Awk 4.0.2` version

Comment: `GNU Awk 4.0.2` should work. I would check the output of `hdfs`, just in case.

Comment: yes I checked, paths and files exists, nn problem, for exemple `
`-rw-r--r--   3 svchdp hdfs    1868962 2021-10-22 16:05 /rec/flux_entrant/archive/le501/tble91_formation_eligible/20211022-154811/part-m-00002.deflate`, we can see the date `20211022-154811`

Comment: maybe the date format is not good ? maybe we should convert it to date format instead of string... it's weird because string format should work

Comment: We need more accuracy. Please edit your question and post the exact output of the `hdfs` command, and check the command `hdfs dfs -ls /rec/flux_entrant/archive/le501/tble91_formation_eligible/* | awk -v startdate="20220110" 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{6}"}($1 >= startdate){print $1}'` for typos. Changing a `'` into `"` v.gr. can break the command.

Comment: @Pierre François, thank you, it gives the good result. The issue that I had first was no files having date => `20220110` in `rec` environnent, when i tested it in other env, it is working very well, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you actually want something like this to start from:

```
$ hdfs dfs ls -d /path/to/dir/*/
```

This will select all subdirectories under `/path/to/dir` and not traverse them due to the flag `-d` (See [hadoop documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls). From that point forward it is straightforward to make the directory selection. The directory is of the form `YYYYMMDD-hhmmss` and therefor lexicographically sortable. So you could just do something like this:

```
$ hdfs dfs ls -d /path/to/dir/*/ | awk -F/ '($NF<"20220128"){print $NF}'
```

Notice that we do a string comparison and not a numerical comparison in `$NF<"20220128"`. Due to the internals of awk, you could do a numeric comparison as well as awk will strip all non-numeric parts of a string in it's conversion. So you could do:

```
$ hdfs dfs ls -d /path/to/dir/*/ | awk -F/ '($NF+0<20220128){print $NF}'
```